What's a professional way I can "smart warp" a series of similar objects?
As part of a multi-object mockup I'm creating, I'd like to apply a curved distortion so that it looks like the pages are somewhat rotating around the surface of a sphere.
Each individual object should be replaceable, but I'm struggling to deduce how to accomplish this without manually distorting each individual piece. Is there a streamlined method to apply a distortion to a group of smart objects?

Create a Smart Object, distort the Smart Object.
You can then replace the interior contents of the Smart Object and the distortion will remain.
By default, if you copy a Smart Object and then alter the interior contents of the copy, all Smart Objects update to reflect the new content.
To circumvent this behavior - due to needing multiple different images all distorted in the same manner -  highlight the first Smart Object in the Layers Panel and then choose "New Smart Object via Copy" from the Layers Panel Menu. This will create an identical Smart Object, but without the contents being connected to the original Smart Object - allowing you to replace contents in the copy without altering other Smart Objects. But the distortions will all remain.
